# how to separate each content in the file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a text file (more then 1GB in size) and it contains lines like these:

```
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

all strings staring with like below,  .....

```
10830110
1083021
10840110
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100
1086022100
```

i need separate 8 files, how to do with sed command

Comment: Do you have any attempts yet? Why the restriction to use sed? I have an idea how to do this with egrep.

Comment: Sheldon no ,sed may be easy, any other idea welcome...

Comment: The example pattern string `10840110` is repeated two times(*probably by mistake ... so please edit your question to correct that*) in your question ... Therefore I used 7 patterns in my answer as the patterns need to be unique or otherwise you will get duplicate lines in the output.

Comment: How do you want to separate the file? Do you just need to have 8 files of the same size (or as close as possible) or do you want to separate them based on the first few numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use sed to turn your file of prefixes into a file of sed commands, then use that in a sed command to process the large file - this will almost certainly be more efficient than using a shell loop to run sed (or grep) multiple times on the same (large) file. Ex. given

```
$ cat file2
10830110
1083021
10840110
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100
1086022100
```

then

```
$ sed 's:.*:/^&/w&.txt:' file2
/10830110/w10830110.txt
/1083021/w1083021.txt
/10840110/w10840110.txt
/10840110/w10840110.txt
/1088022100/w1088022100.txt
/10850110/w10850110.txt
/1085022100/w1085022100.txt
/1086022100/w1086022100.txt
```

so that

```
$ sed 's:.*:/^&/w&.txt:' file2 | sed -n -f - file1
```

produces

```
$ head 108*.txt
==> 10830110.txt <==

==> 1083021.txt <==
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17

==> 10840110.txt <==
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff

==> 10850110.txt <==
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9

==> 1085022100.txt <==
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62

==> 1086022100.txt <==
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50

==> 1088022100.txt <==
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
```

You may want to de-duplicate the pattern file first - and possibly sort it numerically and modify the second sed command to break after the first match, so that you only match the *longest* prefix:

```
$ sort -nru file2 | sed 's:.*:/^&/{w&.txt\nb\n}:' | sed -n -f - file1
```

giving

```
$ head 108*.txt
==> 10830110.txt <==

==> 1083021.txt <==
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17

==> 10840110.txt <==
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff

==> 10850110.txt <==
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9

==> 1085022100.txt <==
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62

==> 1086022100.txt <==
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50

==> 1088022100.txt <==
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
```

Comment: *"this will almost certainly be more efficient than using a shell loop to run sed multiple times on the same (large) file."* ... For very large files, yes it is ... That earned an up-vote :-)

Comment: At first-glance, I think it's more efficient to avoid sed entirely and process in a single `read`-type loop (but I haven't tried it yet to prove it to myself), but I do love this answer.  Upvoted simply for the meta approach of using a sed script to write a sed script :-)

Comment: sort -nru file2 | sed 's:.*:/^&/{w&.txt\nb\n}:' | sed -n -f - file1 --- it is working perfectly Thankyou

Answer (score 7):

#### prefix.text (contains the 8 prefixes)

```
1prefix
2prefix
3prefix
4prefix
x1prefix
x2prefix
x3prefix
x4prefix
```

#### input.text (like your 1 GB text file)

```
1prefix90956666
3prefix26588388
1prefix49080634
x3prefix59162307
x1prefix86437679
x4prefix77832956
x3prefix56458412
2prefix37484977
x2prefix73879936
x1prefix44005273
2prefix57156422
x1prefix67751608
4prefix25566629
x2prefix93657051
x3prefix40897616
4prefix93222501
3prefix35680804
x4prefix42979833
x2prefix08229240
1prefix42071365
4prefix67857600
2prefix66384962
x4prefix21482824
3prefix59616880
```

#### loop with grep, to write 1 output file per 1 prefix

```
while read prefix
do
    grep "^${prefix}" input.text > output_${prefix}.text
done < prefix.text
```

#### output_x1prefix.text (output example)

```
x1prefix86437679
x1prefix44005273
x1prefix67751608
```

Comment: This will require reading the entire enormous file once per prefix. Also, `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`. In any case, you don't need `grep -E` or `egrep` here, a simple `grep` would do the same.

Comment: Thank you @terdon, i have replaced `egrep` with `grep`.

Comment: @terdon It seems this answer provide the fastest solution to the OP so far ... As per the **methbusters** :-)  ... Kindly see the **Speed test** part in  my answer and let me know the results you get if you happen to test the solutions ... Sheldon I have already up-voted your answer so can't up-vote it again although I would if I could :-)

Comment: @Raffa well, I'll be... Sheldon, looks like I owe you an apology! I still feel that reading the file multiple times is inefficient, but I also ran a test and got the same result as Raffa, so I was clearly wrong. Sorry!

Comment: Any reason why you picked `.text` instead of `.txt` or `.tmp`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, i enjoy my freedom since the times of DOS filename restrictions (8.3) are over :-)

Comment: @Sheldon Can't argue with that. It is a good reason.

Answer (score 7):

This will create a new file for each matched pattern with an extension of `.splt` in the current working directory and write all matching lines to it:

`sed` in a shell `for` loop:

```bash
for i in "10830110" "1083021" "10840110" "1088022100" "10850110" "1085022100" "1086022100" # Patterns to match
    do
    sed -n "/^$i/p" FileName > "$i.splt" # Change "FileName" to your file name
    done
```

You can do the same, as well, with `awk` in a shell `for` loop:

```bash
for i in "10830110" "1083021" "10840110" "1088022100" "10850110" "1085022100" "1086022100" # Patterns to match
    do
    awk -v pat="^$i" -v pat2="$i" '$0 ~ pat { print $0 > pat2".splt"}' FileName # Change "FileName" to your file name
    done
```

`awk` with an array of patterns:

```bash
awk '{pat["0"] = "10830110";
    pat["1"] = "1083021";
    pat["2"] = "10840110";
    pat["3"] = "1088022100";
    pat["4"] = "10850110";
    pat["5"] = "1085022100";
    pat["6"] = "1086022100";} {for (i in pat) { if ($0 ~ "^"pat[i]) print $0 > pat[i]".splt"}}' YourFile
```

or save patterns as lines(*each pattern on a new line*) in a `pat.txt` file and let `awk` build the array of patterns like so:

```bash
awk 'FILENAME=="pat.txt" { pat[$i]=$0; next } { for (i in pat) { if ($0 ~ "^"pat[i]) print $0 > pat[i]".splt"}}' pat.txt YourFile
```

---

#### Speed test (*for science*)

I tested the solutions(*tested 3 times each and took the rounded average*) provided in my answer as well as in the answers by [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1420678/968501) and [@Sheldon](https://askubuntu.com/a/1420645/968501) and here are the results(*tested on the same average specifications PC*) with the same patterns `pat.txt` contains:

```bash
$ cat pat.txt 
10830110
1083021
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100
1086022100
```

and the data file `file.dat` is a `1.1G` containing `8,484,000` lines which is made by duplicating the lines in the example provided by the OP i.e.:

```
1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17
10840110dbd43121ef0c51a8ba62193eac247f57f1909e270eeb53d68da60ad61519f19cfb0511ec2431ca54e2fcabf6fa985615ec06def5ba1b753e8ad96d0564aa4c
1084011028375c62fd132d5a4e41ffef2419da345b6595fba8a49b5136de59a884d878fc9789009843c49866a0dc97889242b9fb0b8c112f1423e3b220bc04a2d7dfbdff
10880221005f0e261be654e4c52034d8d05b5c4dc0456b7868763367ab998b7d5886d64fbb24efd14cea668d00bfe8048eb8f096c3306bbb31aaea3e06710fa8c0bb8fca71
108501103461fca7077fc2f0d895048606b828818047a64611ec94443e52cc2d39c968363359de5fc76df48e0bf3676b73b1f8fea5780c2af22c507f83331cc0fbfe6ea9
1085022100a4ce8a09d1f28e78530ce940d6fcbd3c1fe2cb00e7b212b893ce78f8839a11868281179b4f2c812b8318f8d3f9a598b4da750a0ba6054d7e1b743bb67896ee62
1086022100638681ade4b306295815221c5b445ba017943ae59c4c742f0b1442dae4902a56d173a6f859dc6088b6364224ec17c4e2213d9d3c96bd9992b696d7c13b234b50
```

The results are ordered from the fastest on top and the code I used for timing is provided under each result:

#### #1 `grep` in a shell loop @Sheldon (18 seconds)

```bash
s=$(date +%s); while read prefix
do
    grep "^${prefix}" file.dat > ${prefix}.splt
done < pat.txt; e=$(date +%s); echo $(($e-$s))
```

More accurate timing:

```bash
$ time (while read prefix
do
    grep "^${prefix}" file.dat > ${prefix}.splt
done < pat.txt)

real    0m17.969s
user    0m4.437s
sys     0m2.176s
```

#### #2 `sed` @steeldriver (20 seconds)

```bash
s=$(date +%s); sed 's:.*:/&/w&.splt:' pat.txt | sed -n -f - file.dat; e=$(date +%s); echo $(($e-$s))
```

More accurate timing with `^` added in response to [the comment by @terdon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420638/how-to-separate-each-content-in-the-file#comment2472635_1420653):

```bash
$ time (sed 's:.*:/^&/w&.splt:' pat.txt | sed -n -f - file.dat)

real    0m18.748s
user    0m10.408s
sys     0m1.546s
```

#### #3 `sed` in a shell loop @Raffa (21 seconds)

```bash
s=$(date +%s); for i in "10830110" "1083021" "10840110" "1088022100" "10850110" "1085022100" "1086022100" # Patterns to match
    do
    sed -n "/^$i/p" file.dat > "$i.splt" # Change "FileName" to your file name
    done; e=$(date +%s); echo $(($e-$s))
```

#### #4 `awk` in a shell loop @Raffa (35 seconds)

```bash
s=$(date +%s); for i in "10830110" "1083021" "10840110" "1088022100" "10850110" "1085022100" "1086022100" # Patterns to match
    do
    awk -v pat="^$i" -v pat2="$i" '$0 ~ pat { print $0 > pat2".splt"}' file.dat # Change "FileName" to your file name
    done; e=$(date +%s); echo $(($e-$s))
```

#### #5 `awk` @Raffa (414 seconds) <-- That was a shock

```bash
s=$(date +%s); awk '{pat["0"] = "10830110";
    pat["1"] = "1083021";
    pat["2"] = "10840110";
    pat["3"] = "1088022100";
    pat["4"] = "10850110";
    pat["5"] = "1085022100";
    pat["6"] = "1086022100";} {for (i in pat) { if ($0 ~ "^"pat[i]) print $0 > pat[i]".splt"}}' file.dat; e=$(date +%s); echo $(($e-$s))
```

Comment: Nice! However, steeldriver's answer had an error: they had forgotten to add a `^` to only match the beginning of the line. Adding that (see updated answer) makes steeldriver's sed approach as fast as the grep loop on my system.

Comment: @terdon It comes close but `grep` in a loop is still leading :-) ... It even uses less CPU time! ... See the updated speed test above.

Comment: As the prefixes are fixed previously (pun intended), could be interesting to test if using `grep -F` string regex optimization would be faster than normal `grep`.

Comment: @Fjor No, not really ... It even took a couple more seconds as it seems to process the through the whole lines with the absence of `^` as it's obviously a regular expression and cant be used with `-F` ... So I tried with `grep -P "^\Q${prefix}\E"` enabling Perl style regular expressions trying to get the best of the two worlds, but this even took a few more seconds than `grep -F "${prefix}"` ... I would imagine that `-F` when used with `-x` to match whole lines from beginning to end of the line would be the most efficient use case.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already split in to lines which start with these strings, as it is in the example, you can use `awk` in a way as this ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16286795/6543935)):

```bash
 awk '{file="file."(++i)".txt"}{print > file;}' input-file.txt
```

This will produce a new file for each line.

If we suppose the starting strings have fixed length of 7 character (which is not the case in the example), we can split the input file into separate files for each starting string string by something like ([reference](https://www.unix.com/302451251-post2.html)):

```bash
awk '{file="file."(substr($1,1,7))".txt"}{print >> file;}' input-file.txt
```

Comment: starting prefix was 10830110..1083021
10840110
10840110
1088022100
10850110
1085022100,
1086022100. so many lines in the 1gb.starting with mentioned strings...i need 10830110.txt,1083021.txt  ................1086022100.txt

Comment: Hi, @maa, I've updated the answer with a solution for starting strings with a fixed length. If the starting strings have different length and you need to apply different logic, like in the other answers, it is better to implement this logic via `awk` to achieve satisfactory performance.

Comment: each one starting with different length 1083021106e581c71003b987a75f18543cf5858b9fcfc5e04c0dddd79cd18764a865ba86d027de6d1900dc171e4d90a0564abbce99b812b821bd0d7d37aad72ead19c17