# Run multiple command in multiple background screen

Tags: command-line, bash, screen

I have a long-running process command and I am splitting it into 10. This is why I am trying to run 10 commands instead of 1 using `screen`.  If I open the screen manually and run those commands one after another then it is going fine. But I want to automate the task. This is why I wrote the following shell script. Unfortunately sometimes a few of the screens not loaded automatically.

```
screen -dmS Screen01
screen -S Screen01 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen02
screen -S Screen02 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen03
screen -S Screen03 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen04
screen -S Screen04 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen05
screen -S Screen05 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen06
screen -S Screen06 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen07
screen -S Screen07 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen08
screen -S Screen08 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen09
screen -S Screen09 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'

screen -dmS Screen10
screen -S Screen10 -p 0 -X stuff 'Some command that run for more than 20 hours\n'
```

Sometimes it there is `Screen07` missing sometimes `Screen04` missing and sometimes multiples are missing.

How can I automate this process?

Comment: Try inserting a brief pause (like `sleep 2`) between actions.

Comment: You most likely don't need screen to keep your process running after you disconnect. You can use `bash`'s job control instead ... See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1460233 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1461645

Comment: you do not need the "screen -dmS ScreenNN" Plus put it all in a for-loop with a sleep at the end of the loop

Comment: @Rinzwind, can not use for loop, there are a few parameters in the Commands those are not the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add those details then. I really don't understand why you would want to complicate things by using `screen`. If you explain exactly what functionality you need, we will be able to help more.